# Avoid memory leak with delete in C++

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have the following code :

```
class A{
    A(){}; 
};

class B{
    A **a; 
    public:
    B(){
        a = new A*[10];
    }
    ~B(){
        delete[] a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    B* b1 = new B();
    
    //delete B;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know what is the proper delete for dynamic object b1 in main? From what I understand, we don't need to add a delete in main since the object B as a dynamic array of pointers and calls the destructor on return. Is that right?

Comment: I just wanna say one word to you, one word: _Plastics_. Err I meant _smart pointers_ of course. _Smart pointers_. Ugh ok that's two. Damn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we don't need to add a delete in main since the object B as a dynamic array of pointers and calls the destructor on return. Is that right?

No, that's wrong.

If you allocate something with `new` and don't deallocate that pointer with `delete`, then the allocation will leak.

P.S. `B` is very unsafe because it is copyable, but copying it will cause undefined behaviour.

> what is the proper delete for dynamic object b1 in main?

`b1` isn't a dynamic object. It is a pointer, which points to a dynamic object.

Proper way to manage dynamic allocations is to not use bare owning pointers. Also, you unnecessary dynamic allocation should be avoided. Example:

```
class B{
    std::vector<A*> a;
public:
    B() : a(10){}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: @user14645785 Destructor of the class `B` will be invoked only if an object of type `B` is destroyed.

Comment: Yeah and from what I read in my lecture, destructor of a class is invoked on return of the main, so woudln't the object B deleted on return?

Comment: @user14645785 No. Only automatic objects are destroyed upon return. Your `main` contains one automatic variable which is a pointer. A pointer is trivially destructible and its destruction has no side-effects.

Comment: @user14645785 most operating systems will free the memory (expcetions might be shared memory) that was allocated while the application was running (which is roughly at the point when you return from `main`),  but that is an OS specific behavior and not guranteed. In the context of your application `B* b1 = new B();` is leaking, this might not be a problem in this specific case, because the OS will free all the memory. But if you aquired some resources which would only be freed when the corresponding functions in the destructor have been called, then those resources won't be freed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `delete` if you used `new` to create an object:

```
B* b1 = new B();
...    
delete b1;
```

Or, you could use smart pointers, they will call `delete` for you:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b1( new B );
```

Note: To use `unique_ptr`, you'll need to include `<memory>`.

Comment: ok thank you, even if there's a delete in destructor of class B?

Comment: "delete in destructor of class B" deletes B attributes. For every `new` there must be a `delete`. There's a `new` in B constructor for `a` attribute so there must be a `delete` in its destructor for `a` attribute.

Comment: @user14645785 -- if you created it with `new B` you `delete` the pointer; if you created it with `new B[something]` you `delete[]` the pointer. That's all there is to it.